# Model relations for Workers/Jobs/Orders all working in sync

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I am attempting to have customers place an `Order` and when they place an `Order` it will have a `status: uncompleted` in the `Order` database entry.

A `Worker` can claim one of those `Order`s and begin a `Job`. When the `Worker` has taken the `Order` and made it a `Job` I am attempting to make the `Order` status `status: inprogress` and the `Job` status `status: inprogress` and then when the `Worker` completed the `Job` the `Order` status should be `status: completed` and the `Job` status `status: completed`.

I am wondering if I have set up my Model relations the correct way to be able to alter the `status` of `Order` and `Job` when a `Worker` creates a `Job` within a PostgreSQL database.

My models are set up like so:

worker.rb

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

has_many :jobs
```

order.rb

```
belongs_to :job
```

job.rb

```
 belongs_to :worker
 has_one :worker
```

Comment: A `Job` `belongs_to :worker` instead of `user`, because there is no `User` model in this question. You might need to change that in the database too.

Comment: @spickermann thanks for pointing that out! I changed it from user to worker for clarity in the question

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve such functionality by using [sql triggers](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/an-introduction-to-triggers-part-i) or [ActiveRecord callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html). Particularly [after_update callback](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Callbacks/after_update). The idea is when you update a record data some code executes.

Or you can use state machine gems for managing your statuses. [AASM gem](https://github.com/aasm/aasm) for example has build in callbacks which are executed when status changes.

Comment: But do you think I have set up my model relations correctly?